# Using MongoDB Atlas with Flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, mongodb-atlas, flutter-packages

I want to create a Flutter mobile application and I want to use MongoDB Atlas as a database. Is there a Flutter package available that can help me with that?

If not, is there any other way I can connect Flutter to a MongoDB Atlas Database? If there isn't, what other options do you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should create an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the package [mongo_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart/), here is the catch in the database URL give URL to your MongoDB atlas database and you will be able to perform all the crud operations as usual. The documentation is pretty well written so you wouldn't have to face any pro

Comment: I think they do not support it? did you try it? BTW should I include `srv` or not?

Comment: @RohitNishad ye i have tried it you can find tut0rla on youtube.

Comment: yeah I found it, even I write a blog on this topic, https://360techexplorer.com/connect-flutter-to-mongodb/ , BTW thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As @JideGuru said, what you'll want is some form of API that you can then make requests to from your app.

i.e. Instead of accessing your DB directly, you'd do something in Flutter like `http.get("yourserveraddress.com/getSomethingWithThisNumber/1")` using the HTTP package.

I'd recommend looking at something like Node.JS (https://nodejs.org/), which is a runtime for Javascript that allows it to be ran on servers. I'm just getting started with it and for basic CRUD (Create, read, update, delete) operations on my SQL database its been perfect. I'm not a JS developer by any stretch, but it is easy enough to pick up.

You really should never have your database being directly accessed by a client, as that means leaving it exposed on the internet!

MongoDB have their own driver for NodeJS, I've used it with atlas and it seems solid.
(https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

Hope this helps!